# Error 403: disallowed_useragent for a node.js web-site

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

I have one problem with authentication via Google social profile and hope you can help me out.

A few months ago one client reported to me a problem with logging into my website from a mobile device (Android) using a Google profile. It took me a while when could reproduce it.

So, I have a website ([www.uvvo.eu](https://www.uvvo.eu/)), which is just a website and not a mobile application. My website is based on node.js and uses passport.js for authentication with Google.

#### Minimal reproducible example

In macOS Venture 13.0, using the web browser MS Edge v.106.0.1370.52 in Developer Tools when I reduce the size of the screen to the size of a mobile device (*e.g.* 375 x 667 pixels or 390 x 844) logging in with Google stops working and I get “Error 403: disallowed_useragent”. With larger resolutions logging in with Google is working.

In Windows 10, with the same web browser logging in works for all resolutions. Using iPhone and MS Edge, everything works also fine.

I checked the Google OAuth documentation. And it looks like this problem is related to WebView. However, all the fixes I could find are related to the mobile Apps, and not to the websites.

Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: There are 43 questions on stack overflow with the title of [Error 403: disallowed_useragent](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Error+403%3A+disallowed_useragent)  None of them helped?   If so please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: @DalmTo 
Yes, I have checked these 43 questions. Most of them do not have any answer and the rest are about fixing this issue in Apps. In my case, I do not develop an App, but a common website. And everything works fine in my desktop web browser until I reduce the screen resolution to the size of a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

Google has updated its security restrictions for OAuth flow.
They no longer allow native web-views to initiate OAuth flows, but rather are encouraging people to use the OS browsers to do so.

More information is available in the [Google blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html)

Comment: Does it mean that a desktop version of MS Edge on macOS switches automatically to web views when I reduce the screen resolution? If yes, why it does not switch to web views under Windows?

Comment: This is your code thats using a web view.

Comment: What should I change in my code not to use a web view?